# 404 error while debugging in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jboss-eap-6

I am facing a weird issue. 
Login.jsp is my welcome page that I have configured in web.xml. Path:Web_INF/views/login.jsp. User,after authentication is redirected to home page,where I am populating my form from db data.
Now,
When I run my app, Login.jsp appears in eclipse  browser. But when I hit Debug on server-> it pops me up with an 404 request not available error.
Any help on the issue is appreciated. Console Info while DEbugging:

```
19:23:10,345 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.6.Final-redhat-1
19:23:10,633 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.1.5.Final-redhat-1
19:23:10,744 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0.Final-redhat-21) starting
19:23:12,479 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found DAT.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called DAT.war.dodeploy
19:23:12,510 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO Version 3.0.13.GA-redhat-1
19:23:12,510 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
19:23:12,511 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.13.GA-redhat-1
19:23:12,581 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
19:23:12,591 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
19:23:12,614 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS010153: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
19:23:12,617 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013371: Activating Security Subsystem
19:23:12,642 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS013370: Current PicketBox version=4.1.1.Final-redhat-1
19:23:12,643 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBoss Remoting version 3.3.4.Final-redhat-1
19:23:12,687 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
19:23:12,689 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.0.31.Final-redhat-1)
19:23:12,732 WARN  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) JBAS012614: JSF version slot '1.2' is missing from module javax.faces.api
19:23:12,733 WARN  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) JBAS012614: JSF version slot '1.2' is missing from module com.sun.jsf-impl
19:23:12,743 WARN  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) JBAS012614: JSF version slot 'main' is missing from module javax.faces.api
19:23:12,743 WARN  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) JBAS012614: JSF version slot 'main' is missing from module com.sun.jsf-impl
19:23:12,743 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) JBAS012615: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main, 1.2]
19:23:12,829 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
19:23:12,830 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
19:23:12,975 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
19:23:13,069 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 11.1)
19:23:13,284 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/jdbc/DMTWebDS]
19:23:13,359 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/jdbc/intbrkr_ds]
19:23:13,678 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.3.4.Final-redhat-1
19:23:13,795 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory D:\Softwares\EAP-6.4.0\standalone\deployments
19:23:13,805 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of " DAT.war" (runtime-name: " DAT.war")
19:23:14,391 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
19:23:14,397 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:4447
19:23:14,399 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
19:23:14,418 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
19:23:14,558 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
19:23:16,256 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
19:23:16,307 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
19:23:16,499 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 12.1)
19:23:16,666 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) JBAS018210: Register web context: / DAT
19:23:16,686 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/ DAT]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
19:23:16,797 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/ DAT]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet ' DAT '
19:23:16,797 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) FrameworkServlet ' DAT ': initialization started
19:23:16,807 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace ' DAT -servlet': startup date [Sat Jun 11 19:23:16 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
19:23:16,912 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/ DAT -servlet.xml]
19:23:17,353 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
```

Comment: There's not enough details here to help. If your server is loading resources from its own directory, whereas your debugging session references a resource not in its local webcontext, then yeah, you'll get a 404

Comment: Cld u pls brief me tat?? If tats the case, how to sort it out?? Also to your note, I was able to debug till  yesterday!!

Comment: Okay, so please [edit] your question to include what has changed between the working state and now.

Comment: It's probably a debugging configuration issue so you should either check your debug configuration or share more details about it so we can help.

Comment: I sorted it out somehow, but still confused of what exactly happened!! This is what I did:First, rebuild and Redeployed: Even then,Debug didnt work!! Then I just commented out my Dao class and simply tried with my welcome list alone!! Debugging mode worked!! Then, I uncommented the DAOand Tried! Fortunately, it worked !! kind of puzzled in understanding the cause ! !